# React Native ou Ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic, desempenho, comparação, react-native

Preciso criar um App e gostaria de saber qual das tuas tecnologias é a mais indicada pra desenvolvimento mobile atualmente.

- Qual a principal diferença entre ReactNative e Ionic?
- Qual das tecnologias é a mais performática?
- Em qual a curva de aprendizado é menor?

Comment: Vale lembrar que também temos nessa "briga" NativeScript, que tem uma proposta semelhante ao ReactNative e também pode ser usado em conjunto com ambiente Angular. Entre Ionic e NS, NS já está tomando a frente. Agora entre NS e RN, acredito que seja mais uma questão de preferência.

Comment: Não conhecia até então mas vou dar uma olhada. Porém esses dias li um artigo que parece ser bem promissor e que talvez diminua um pouco esse mundo dos Apps nativo, então no futuro pode ser que nem React Native nem Ionic nem NativeScript mas sim PWA. https://medium.com/@marcosflorencio/progressive-web-apps-futuro-b1ea15277aeb

Comment: PWA é um conceito e já pode ser usado. Mas ainda esse ele terá algumas limitações, visto que nada mais é do que um WebSite renderizado de modo diferente. Mas para acessar algumas funções nativas do celular, ainda será necessário um app. Pelo menos até o momento. A questão é, até onde o tempo e dinheiro gasto na criação de app serão mais vantajosos para você? Se for só para dizer que tem um app, vale a pena repensar o projeto. Mas belo artigo!

Comment: @celsomtrindade, O react native é apenas uma linguagem intermediária (no caso JS), que é convertido na linguagem da
plataforma e depois compilado?
Ou é javascript rodando mesmo sobre um VM js (como o v8 ou browser headless) que tem 
um wrapper para o código nativo UI?

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net dê uma olhada na resposta do bigown, ela responde isso que você questiona

Comment: @celsomtrindade, não é exatamente o que eu perguntei, mas pesquisando melhor, achei o que queria saber, está em: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-key-difference-between-ReactNative-and-NativeScript/answer/Valentin-Stoychev

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net podemos dizer RN é 99% nativo e aquele 1% é na VM ;)

Comment: Esse artigo ([clique](https://medium.com/@felipeblini/desenvolvimento-de-aplicativos-m%C3%B3veis-com-javascript-ionic-react-native-e-nativescript-c303b17fba0d)) é bastante esclarecedor!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Deve saber que ambos tentam resolver o mesmo problema de facilitar o desenvolvimento *cross-platform* usando tecnologias web.

React Native tende ser mais rápido porque usa os componentes nativos sempre. Mas possui uma curva de aprendizado maior porque foge um pouco do que as pessoas estão acostumadas (usa [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)). Claro que depende do que está acostumado. Se souber AngularJS, já facilita um pouco. O fato é que não há uma diferença gritante para um lado ou outro.

**Ionic é uma tecnologia híbrida e não nativa**. Ela tenta reproduzir o comportamento de cada plataforma e pode ou não recorrer aos componentes nativos, mesmo que use algo nativo, será indiretamente, então não só a performance será inferior, mas nem sempre parece que está usando algo feito para aquele sistema operacional. Se começar usar *plugins* para melhorar a experiência, começa complicar o desenvolvimento.

**React Native é nativo mesmo**, ainda que usando tecnologias web, e produz uma melhor experiência para o usuário.

Ser nativo ajuda na performance e na [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design).

Você tende a desenvolver um pouco mais rápido com Ionic, fez a aplicação, funciona assim mesmo em "todas" plataformas. É preciso um pouco mais de esforço com React Native.

Talvez a principal diferença é que o Ionic é "write once, deploy everywhere e o React Native é "learn once, write everywhere", pelo menos é o que se costuma dizer deles.

Não deixe de considerar outras possibilidades que podem ser melhores que estas para o seu caso. É aquela coisa de sempre, não tem um claro vencedor. Tem que pegar ambos, experimentar até achar o que será mais indicado para cada projeto.

A decisão é se vai custar mais barato, em tese, ou se vai oferecer um produto melhor, em tese.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Agora ficou claro! Quanto a performance acho que é indiscutível que o React Native é o vencedor, sendo que o Ionic ainda roda em cima de uma Webview.

Comment: Já desenvolvi aplicativos comerciais com cordova (que é onde o Ionic roda) e foi sofrível. É bem rápido pra criar o app, mas conforme a gente vai adicionando funcionalidades, mais plugins precisam ser adicionados, e os plugins do cordova são muito frágeis, sempre tem problema de conflito de versão ou de plataforma. Enfim, não recomendo Ionic/phonegap/cordova para aplicativos médios ou grandes, não tanto por causa da performance, mas sim porque os plugins são uma dor de cabeça desgraçada.

Comment: Excelente ver este ponto de vista. Venho trabalhando com Ionic há alguns meses já, e resolvi pesquisar pelo React Native. Ionic realmente é muito ágil para alavancar o desenvolvimento do app, ainda mais se o desenvolvedor estiver "fluente" em Javascript/Typescript. Porém, também é fato que várias complicações aparecem com o tempo e tamanho do app, então nesses casos  mais elaborados, talvez valha a pena investir em aprender React.

Answer (score 11):

Ionic é um framework JS para fazer aplicações híbridas usando HTML, CSS e JS.
Você precisa usar plugins adaptados e APIs para utilizar as funções nativas do aparelho.

Já o React Native é uma ferramenta(toolbox) que utiliza os componentes nativos do aparelho e liga uns aos outros para assim montar um aplicativo Nativo. Por exemplo, você não precisa usar o CSS para estilizar os componentes UI, pois serão utilizadoa os componentes nativos da plataforma.

Pro exemplo:
Ionic = blocos genéricos de lego(aquela marca mais barata)
você constrói um castelo que fica parecido com o de lego, tem as mesmas funcionalidades, mas não tem a mesma performance de um castelo nativo.

React Native = Blocos de Lego Originais que você só precisa aprender a ligar uns aos outros usando uma cola especial(React Native) pra montar um castelo NATIVO.

No meu ponto de vista Ionic ainda esta na frente por existir a mais tempo, tem uma comunidade maior e uma porção maior de exemplos e tutoriais por ai, por usar o Angular voce tem uma escalabilidade maior quando se trata de projetos grandes.

Ja o React Native ainda é um bebê comparado a outros frameworks, com uma comunidade relativamente menor mas tão ativa quanto. Perfeito para projetos menores/pessoais.

Minha opinião: 
Crie 2 projetos idênticos em ambas plataformas, teste suas funcionalidades e performance. Veja qual você se adapta melhor, no final das contas tudo se resume à qual linguagem você se identifica mais.

Comment: Segui seu conselho, mas apesar de ficar mais a vontade com angular eu decidi usar React Native. Mesmo sendo uma tecnologia mais jovem não vejo problema em arriscar de construir meu App com React Native.

Comment: Ai sim @LuKsSys Depois conte-nos como ficou seu app, se tiver algum problema com o React, é so contactar. Te aconselho a entrar na comunidade React Native Developers no Facebook.... a galera la ajuda muito! Ahh se quiser votar a minha resposta como certa hehe =D

Answer (score -3):

Para quem quiser saber melhor como o react funciona por baixo, esse é um excelente artigo https://medium.com/nutripad/react-native-webview-ou-realmente-nativo-4e30a37ae020:

> React Native é JS rodando em uma VM e controlando a UI nativa
>
> É importante notar que sua aplicação começa no ambiente nativo, e o nativo então faz chamadas através da ponte e inicia sua app JS.

Outros links interessantes são:

http://www.reactnative.com/under-the-hood-of-react-native/

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-key-difference-between-ReactNative-and-NativeScript/answer/Valentin-Stoychev