# Qual a linguagem de programação para criar aplicações Android?

Tags: android, mobile

Qual a linguagem de programação utilizada, para criar a maioria das aplicações mobile Android?

Como por exemplo, aplicações de guias, perguntas etc...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Java e Kotlin são as linguagens "oficiais" da plataforma. Não importa o que vai fazer, essencialmente é o que vai usar. Então esta é a resposta objetiva para a pergunta é que Java é a mais usada disparado.

Já oficializou [Kotlin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221905/101).

Mas não quer dizer que só ela pode ser usada. Não digo maioria, mas muita gente usa outras coisas. Vejo cada vez mais usarem C# ou outra linguagem .NET usando [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/).

[NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html) é uma forma de usar C e C++ e algumas pessoas usam.

Parece que a Google resolveu investir em tornar [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/platforms) uma linguagem forte no Android.

Se preferir uma aplicação híbrida ou mesmo para web, JavaScript passa ser a opção. E muita gente tem usado essa forma, mesmo que nem sempre seja a melhor opção. Tem várias soluções nesse sentido. [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) é apenas uma delas. [Tem outras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170138/101).

Há até quem use [Corona](https://coronalabs.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started-with-corona/).

Só porque eu não citei outras não quer dizer que sejam tão menos usadas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).